# multiple onClickListener on a single Button

Tags: java, android

in my project, I have to use dialogs in different parts of the app and the downside is same code for creating and showing the Dialog used every time! So I decided to make a function for creating and showing a dialog and wherever I need I just call that,

the problem is, there are 2 buttons on my Dialog and before refactoring on the onClickListener I could easily use

```
dialog.dismiss();
// more codes ...
```

in setOnClickListener
but now with the incoming OnClickListener Object, I have no control over the dialog instance ...
this is the function I wrote

```
    public static void warningAndErrorDialog(Activity activity, int titleResourceId, int iconResourceId, int contentResourceId
        , HashMap<CustomDialogButton, View.OnClickListener> buttons) {

    Typeface iranSansFont = setFont(activity, FontStyle.IRAN_SANS_REGULAR);
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);

    CustomFontTextView cftvTitle = (CustomFontTextView)
            dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtViwDialogTitle);
    if(activity.getString(titleResourceId) != null)
         cftvTitle.setText(titleResourceId);
    else cftvTitle.setText(" ");

    CustomFontTextView cftvContent = (CustomFontTextView)
            dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtViwDialogContent);
    if(activity.getString(contentResourceId) != null)
        cftvContent.setText(contentResourceId);
    else cftvTitle.setText(" ");

    ImageView imgViwDialogTitle = dialog.findViewById(R.id.imgViwDialogTitle);
    imgViwDialogTitle.setImageResource(iconResourceId);


    Button btnYes = null;
    Button btnNo = null;

    for (Map.Entry<CustomDialogButton, View.OnClickListener> button : buttons.entrySet())
        switch (button.getKey()) {
            case YES:
                if (btnYes != null) break;
                btnYes = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnYes);
                btnYes.setTypeface(iranSansFont);
                if (button.getValue() != null)
                    btnYes.setOnClickListener(button.getValue());
                break;
            case NO:
                if (btnNo != null) break;
                btnNo = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnNo);
                if (button.getValue() != null) {
                    btnNo.setTypeface(iranSansFont);
                    btnNo.setOnClickListener(button.getValue());
                } else
                    btnNo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                break;
            case OK:
                btnYes = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnYes);
                btnYes.setText(R.string.ok);
                if (button.getValue() != null) btnYes.setOnClickListener(button.getValue());
                else
                    btnYes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                btnNo = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnNo);
                btnNo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                return;
        }


        dialog.show();
}
```

notice of case YES: 
I set button setOnClickListener from an onClickListener I passed to the function.
so I have no control over its content. now How Can I add statement dialog.dismiss(); ?
the Only thing I can think of is finding a way to pass an array of OnClickListener to the setOnCLickListener method.

one for dismissing the dialog and another one for setting the actual job of the button...

ps: I tried dismissing the dialog using setOnTouchListener but as I expected, that did not work...: -?

so what should I do?

final edit :
someone suggested

```
btnYes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                for (View.OnClickListener callback : callbacks)
                    if (callback != null)
                        callback.onClick(view);
            }
        });
```

(callbacks is a List of View.OnClickListener object) and thats the exact answer to "how to add multiple onClickListener on a single Button" question.

but @greenapps solution is the best solution that suits my need, thanks :)

so I share the final version of the code for whom the may concern :D :

public class CustomDialog {

```
private final Dialog dialog;
private Typeface font;
private CustomFontTextView cftvTitle;
private CustomFontTextView cftvContent;
private ImageView imgViwDialogTitle;
private Activity activity;
private Button btnYes;
private Button btnNo;


public CustomDialog(final Activity activity, int titleResourceId, int iconResourceId, int contentResourceId
        , HashMap<CustomDialogButton, View.OnClickListener> buttons) {

    font = Utility.setFont(activity, FontStyle.IRAN_SANS_REGULAR);
    this.activity = activity;
    dialog = new Dialog(this.activity);

    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);

    setTitleTextbyId(titleResourceId);
    setContentTextById(contentResourceId);
    setTitleIconById(iconResourceId);

    setButtons(buttons);

}

public CustomDialog(Activity activity) {
    font = Utility.setFont(activity, FontStyle.IRAN_SANS_REGULAR);
    this.activity = activity;
    dialog = new Dialog(this.activity);

    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);

    setTitleTextbyId(0);
    setContentTextById(0);
    setTitleIconById(0);

    setButtons(null);
}

public void show() {
    dialog.show();
}

public void setButtons(HashMap<CustomDialogButton, View.OnClickListener> buttons) {

    for (final Map.Entry<CustomDialogButton, View.OnClickListener> button : buttons.entrySet())
        switch (button.getKey()) {
            case YES:
                setButtonYes(button);
                break;
            case NO:
                setButtonNo(button);
                break;
            case OK:
                setButtonYes(button);
                btnYes.setText(R.string.ok);
                btnNo = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnNo);
                btnNo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                break;
        }
}

@NonNull
private void setButtonNo(final Map.Entry<CustomDialogButton, View.OnClickListener> button) {

    if (btnNo != null) return;
    btnNo = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnNo);
        btnNo.setTypeface(font);
        btnNo.setOnClickListener(button.getValue());
        btnNo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                    if(button.getValue() != null)
                        button.getValue().onClick(view);
            }
        });
}

@NonNull
private void setButtonYes(final Map.Entry<CustomDialogButton, View.OnClickListener> button) {


    if (btnYes != null) return;
    btnYes = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnYes);
    btnYes.setTypeface(font);
        btnYes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                if(button.getValue() != null)
                    button.getValue().onClick(view);
            }
        });
}

public void setTitleIconById(int iconResourceId) {
    this.imgViwDialogTitle = dialog.findViewById(R.id.imgViwDialogTitle);
    if (activity.getResources().getDrawable(iconResourceId) != null)
        imgViwDialogTitle.setImageResource(iconResourceId);
}

public void setContentTextById(int contentResourceId) {
    this.cftvContent = (CustomFontTextView)
            this.dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtViwDialogContent);
    if (this.activity.getString(contentResourceId) != null)
        cftvContent.setText(contentResourceId);
    else cftvTitle.setText(" ");
}

public void setTitleTextbyId(int titleResourceId) {
    this.cftvTitle = (CustomFontTextView)
            this.dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtViwDialogTitle);
    if (this.activity.getString(titleResourceId) != null)
        cftvTitle.setText(titleResourceId);
    else cftvTitle.setText(" ");
}

public void dismiss() {
    dialog.dismiss();
}
```

}

Comment: You add your OnClickListener object as parameter, so you can define the OnClickListener content where you create this object. What is the problem with this?

Comment: where I create this object , I don't have access to the dialog instance... , I just make an dialog object in the method body not outside of it ...

Comment: Well, I think you dont have to create a static method for this. Instead of create a Singleton class for your dialogs and this class should have a dismiss() method which is public method, so you can access it from anywhere.

Comment: Something like `btnYes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            dialog.dismiss(); button.getValue().click();
                        }
                    }`. ?

Comment: @greenapps yes, exactly what I'm looking for. But there is no Click method on OnClickListener object ...

Comment: @just I think it should be a better way ! because this way it makes some kinda circular situation which I don't really like it ... :(

Comment: @pskink I don't get it , would you show me some sample code?

Comment: `But there is no Click method on OnClickListener object `. No but there is `OnClick()`. So use `button.getValue().OnClick(null);` or . `button.getValue().OnClick(view);` Didn´t i say: `Something like` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
btnYes.setOnClickListener(button.getValue());
```

Change to:

```
btnYes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
   @Override public void onClick(View view) { 
       dialog.dismiss(); 
       button.getValue().onClick(view); 
   }
});
```